# How can I have the respective object in a CollectionView?

Tags: c#, xaml, maui

I'm trying to use a dynamically created layout using `CollectionView` to show a series of properties of a class, all based on a list and I want to make it so one of the properties is a `Combobox`. How do I know what object the `ComboBox` needs to refer to?

Here is my `CollectionView`:

```
<CollectionView x:Name="taskList">
                <CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate x:DataType="models:Task">
                        <VerticalStackLayout Margin="15">
                            <Entry Text="{Binding name}" IsReadOnly="True" />
                            <Entry Text="{Binding departmentsString}" IsReadOnly="True"/>
                            <HorizontalStackLayout>
                                <inputs:SfComboBox BackgroundColor="Black" TextColor="Green" DropDownIconColor="Green"/>
                                <Entry Text="{Binding deadline}" IsReadOnly="True" />
                                <Entry Text="{Binding author.fullName}" IsReadOnly="True"/>
                            </HorizontalStackLayout>
                            <Entry Text="{Binding description}" IsReadOnly="True" />
                        </VerticalStackLayout>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
            </CollectionView>
```

It has its ItemsSource declared like this:

```
taskList.ItemsSource = tasks;
```

tasks being:

```
ObservableCollection<Classes.Task> tasks { get; set; }
```

Here is the Task class:

```
    public class Task
{
    public Task(string name, List<string> departments, Status status, DateOnly deadline, Employee author, string description)
    {
        this.name = name;
        this.departments = departments;
        this.status = status;
        this.deadline = deadline;
        this.author = author;
        this.description = description;
    }

    public string name { get; private set; }
    public List<string> departments { get; private set; } = new List<string>();
    public string departmentsString
    {
        get
        {
            string _ = "";
            foreach (var department in departments)
            {
                _ += department + (department == departments.Last() ? "": ", ");
            }
            return _;
        }
    }
    public Status status { get; private set; }
    public DateOnly deadline { get; private set; }
    public Employee? author { get; set; }
    public string description { get; private set; }
    public List<Employee> employees { get; private set; } = new List<Employee>();

    public void AddEmployee(Employee employee)
    {
        if (departments.Contains(employee.department))
        {
            employees.Add(employee);
        }
    }
}
```

How do I make it so I can determine the instance of the class `Task` depending on which `ComboBox` I change?

Here is what the UI looks like:

Comment: you bind it to a property of your model.  We don't know what your model looks like or what inputs you expect your combobox to have so it's difficult to be more specific.

Comment: @Jason The comboBox will be bind to an Enum. By model, do you mean the class?

Comment: Yes, the `Task` class

Comment: you still haven't told us which property of `Task` you are trying to bind to, or what the `enum` is that will populate the `ComboBox`

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?q=xamarin+bind+enum+site:stackoverflow.com

Comment: @Jason Trying to bind the combobox to the Status property

Comment: then bind the selected property of the `ComboBox` (or whatever similar property SyncFusion uses) to the `status` property of your model

Comment: @Jason How do I do that?

Comment: @Jason I tried doing the following <inputs:SfComboBox BackgroundColor="Black" TextColor="Green" DropDownIconColor="Green" SelectedItem="{Binding status}"/> but it didn't work.

Comment: https://help.syncfusion.com/xamarin/combobox/populating-data

Comment: @Jason It is populated (wasn't included in what I sent you) but it doesn't change in the class instance when I change on the combobox

Comment: @CitrusBoy With the code you supplied, no one can reproduce your problem.

Answer (score 0):

> Trying to bind the combobox to the Status property

You can try to set a data list for property `ItemsSource` of `SfComboBox`  and  bind a field to property `SelectedItem` of `SfComboBox`.

Suppose you would bind `departments` to the `ItemsSource` of `SfComboBox`, then we need to add a field (e.g. `SelectedItem`) to bind to property `SelectedItem` of `SfComboBox`:

Then we need to implement interface `INotifyPropertyChanged`  for `MyTask.cs` and add field `SelectedItem`.(To prevent conflicts with the `Task` class in my project, I named it `MyTask`)

```
        //add SelectedItem here

        private string _selectedItem;
        public string SelectedItem
        {
            get => _selectedItem;
            set => SetProperty(ref _selectedItem, value);
        }
```

The whole code of `MyTask`

```
   public class MyTask: INotifyPropertyChanged 
    {
        public MyTask(string name, List<string> departments, int status, DateTime deadline, Employee author, string description)
        {
            this.name = name;
            this.departments = departments;
            this.status = status;
            this.deadline = deadline;
            this.author = author;
            this.description = description;
        }

        //add SelectedItem here

        private string _selectedItem;
        public string SelectedItem
        {
            get => _selectedItem;
            set => SetProperty(ref _selectedItem, value);
        }

        bool SetProperty<T>(ref T storage, T value, [CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
        {
            if (Object.Equals(storage, value))
                return false;

            storage = value;
            OnPropertyChanged(propertyName);
            return true;
        }

        protected void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
        {
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        public string name { get;  set; }
        public List<string> departments { get; private set; } = new List<string>();
        public string departmentsString
        {
            get
            {
                string _ = "";
                foreach (var department in departments)
                {
                    _ += department + (department == departments.Last() ? "" : ", ");
                }
                return _;
            }
        }
        public int status { get; private set; }
        public DateTime deadline { get; private set; }
        public Employee? author { get; set; }
        public string description { get; private set; }
        public List<Employee> employees { get; private set; } = new List<Employee>();

        public void AddEmployee(Employee employee)
        {
            if (departments.Contains(employee.department))
            {
                employees.Add(employee);
            }
        }
    }
```

Then we can use like this:

```
     <editors:SfComboBox BackgroundColor="Black" TextColor="Green" 
                         DropDownIconColor="Green" 
                         WidthRequest="250"
                         ItemsSource="{Binding departments}"    
                         SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedItem}"
                                            />
```

**Note:**

Then if we change the option of `SfComboBox` , the value of `SelectedItem` will also update automatically.